# Embedding multipage documents in LaTeX documents

Tags: pdf, image, latex

I am writing my dissertation and need to reproduce different short booklets (2-7 pages) that I have used in my studies.

Ideally, I would like to have each page of the booklet appear as a page in my dissertation, but enclosed within some frame and using my dissertation's page numbering, etc.  I have the booklets in Word format but would rather embed them as PDFs so they would look exactly as they did to my subjects.

I can do this manually by splitting each PDF into multiple files and including them separately in my LaTeX.

However, is there some package or macro to achieve this without all this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [pdfpages](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pdfpages) - I've used it before and it has all the features you talk about as far as I remember.