# How do i append a paper in appendix in latex?

Tags: latex

In my Master thesis i want to append a paper as an appendix to the thesis. I am writing in LateX in the "report" style. At the end of the thesis there are some code in Appendix A, and in Appendix B i want to add a paper, written in latex. How do i append the paper at the end, as a standalone paper, with its own bibliography etc?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555154/embedding-multipage-documents-in-latex-documents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the cleaner option consists of using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf). That way rebuilding your document doesn't require appending it again :). The other options aren't really necessary in your case I believe: they mainly concern selecting specific pages and changing the page layout to multiple pages per sheet.

Comment: The problem is you'll have repeating page numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Note very clean, but you could just compile the two files as PDF and the concatenate the them.